# replacing a function passed by reference in javascript

Tags: javascript

My understanding is in javascript a function is passed by reference... and in this case I am trying to replace one function with another. It is not working. I am sure I am missing something simple. But what?

```js
var spit = {
 spittle: function (x) {
  console.log('i spittle at ' + x);
 }
}

replaceFunc = {
 replace: function (func) {
  func = console.log;
 }
}

replaceFunc.replace(spit.spittle);

spit.spittle('joe'); /// should be just 'joe' instead the spittle func is not replaced and it outputs 'i spittle at joe'
```

Comment: There is no pass by reference in javascript, objects are passes as value of a reference, but still as a value.

Comment: so how would i replace the spittle function inside of spit object? like with my chosen substitute of 'console.log' ? I mean via a function, not simply the obvious direct spit.spittle = console.log

Comment: In that case you'd have to target it directly, and not the function argument, as in `spit.spittle = console.log`

Comment: You'd have to write `spit.spittle = function() { /* whatever */ };`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ytjzbfoy/

Comment: @adeneo I was just doing that myself, but got hung up pointing it at `console.log` directly.  Is it just because this is a native function that it needs a wrapper?

Comment: @adeneo IE [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/g0fyq78p/1/), just wondering why I get an "Illegal Invocation" if I try to use `console.log` instead of `x.y`

Comment: Execution context changes, `console` is no longer `this` when used as a reference

Comment: @adeneo Ah, of course

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g0fyq78p/3/

Comment: THANKS DUDES I've been programming JS for years and you taught me something new.

Answer (score 2):

There is no pass by reference in JavaScript. An option is to pass the entire `spit` object and modify it.

```
var spit = {
    spittle: function (x) {
        console.log('i spittle at ' + x);
    }
}

var replaceFunc = {
    replaceSpittle: function (funcContainer) {       
        funcContainer.spittle = function() {
            console.log.apply(console, arguments);
        }
    }
}

replaceFunc.replaceSpittle(spit);

spit.spittle('joe');
```

Answer (score 1):

`replaceFunc.replace(spit.spittle);` passes the function stored in `spit.spittle` into the function stored in `replaceFunc.replace`, therefore, once you're inside of the replace function, it can't get back to the `spittle` property of `spit` other than by directly referencing it as `spit.spittle`.

One workaround would be to pass both the object and the name of the property you want to replace into the function.

```js
var spit = {
 spittle: function (x) {
  console.log('i spittle at ' + x);
 }
}

replaceFunc = {
 replace: function (obj, key) {
  obj[key] = console.log.bind(console);
 }
}

replaceFunc.replace(spit, 'spittle');

spit.spittle('joe'); /// should be just 'joe'
```